# What is the max buffer size for "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have some classic ASP code that runs this line:
`SET xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

But occasionally, and with no warning of course, it dies. Our logs tell us that the "buffers supplied to a function was too small" - I did some looking around, and nothing especially useful comes up, except a post in 2003 where Microsoft says that 1 GB is too big...but not really what the max size is, or how to manipulate the buffer to increase its size, or how to supply a bigger buffer. On the other hand, I would like to know if there is a way to find out what the size is before we move forward in the program...Any thoughts you have are appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using ResponseStream?   https://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/603227-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-works-only-text-files